# DragGesture hangs SwiftUI after adapting simple example

Tags: swiftui, drag

I'm starting out using DragGestures in SwiftUI. I started with a simple internet example, did a couple modifications, everything was working fine. Here's that code:

```
struct DragTest: View {
  @State var viewState = CGSize.zero

  var body: some View {
    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30)
      .fill(Color.blue)
      .frame(width: 300, height: 400 + viewState.height)
      .offset(x:0, y: viewState.height / 2)
      .gesture(
        DragGesture().onChanged { value in
          viewState = value.translation
        }
          .onEnded { value in
            withAnimation(.spring()) {
              viewState = .zero
            }
          }
      )
  }
}
```

But if I change the frame height adjustment to subtract viewstate.height instead of add, the code will hang in preview or in the simulator with 100% processor usage. It seems like some sort of update loop.

```
struct DragTest: View {
  @State var viewState = CGSize.zero

  var body: some View {
    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30)
      .fill(Color.blue)
      .frame(width: 300, height: 400 - viewState.height)
      .offset(x:0, y: viewState.height / 2)
      .gesture(
        DragGesture().onChanged { value in
          viewState = value.translation
        }
          .onEnded { value in
            withAnimation(.spring()) {
              viewState = .zero
            }
          }
      )
  }
}
```

What is going on here? If I don't understand the root cause, I'm not going to get very far with drag gestures.

Comment: Can't really figure out what's going on here really. What are you trying to achieve? I guess it's something about you modifying the gesture position while you are moving it at the same time.

Comment: @NexusUA For what purpose?

Comment: @bjorn.lau At the moment I'm just getting used to the API. The eventual goal was a sort of stretch operation on a drawing. But this was a case of taking an example off the internet, modifying it, seeing it work, and then changing a simple thing and having it not just not work, but hang the whole system. If you trying dragging the first example, you'll see it do something sensible. So why does the second one hang with a tiny change? In other words, it doesn't really require knowing what I want to achieve to ask the question about why the whole system hangs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've sorted this out, though the symptoms on the way to solution were more than confusing. It appears that if you plan on modifying the geometry of an object (`.offset` doesn't do this, but `.frame` does, it seems), then you need to perform the `DragGesture` in a different coordinate space which does not change size during the `DragGesture`. (What coordinate space does `DragGesture` normally operate in? - I don't know, and the documentation I found didn't say). Here is the code that works, plus I tried several variants.

```
struct DragTest3: View {
  @State var trans = CGSize.zero

  var body: some View {
    Group {
      RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30)
        .fill(Color.blue)
        .frame(width: 300, height: 400 - trans.height)
        .gesture(
          DragGesture(coordinateSpace: .named("outer"))
            .onChanged { value in
              trans = value.translation
            }
        )
    }
    .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
    .coordinateSpace(name: "outer")
    .border(.black)
  }
}
```

Most simple `DragGesture` examples on the internet only use the `.offset` modifier, so they don't crash, I couldn't easily find less trivial examples. My theory is that if the coordinate space in which the `DragGesture` is occurring is changing size, the code can enter a death spiral. It would be nice if the mechanisms were described in greater detail somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Can confirm, I also fixed it like Andrew did. In my case, I had to use the "gesture.location.x" and "gesture.location.y" instead of gesture.translation.

```
GeometryReader { geometry in
   VStack {
            ZStack {
               // content...
            }
            .onHover { hovering in
                isHovered = hovering
            }
            
            Text(name)
                .foregroundColor(isHovered ? Color.black : Color.black.opacity(0.6))
        }
        .gesture(
            DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0.10, coordinateSpace: .named("outer"))
            .onChanged { gesture in
                // animation code using gesture.location...
            }
            .onEnded { _ in
                initialDragOffset = .zero
            }
        )
        
        .onHover { hovering in
            isHovered = hovering
        }
        .animation(Animation.spring(), value: isHovered)
        
        .position(
            x: geometry.size.width * style.left,
            y: geometry.size.height * style.top
        )
        .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
        .coordinateSpace(name: "outer")
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35457421)